# Fonts changed on updating distro

Tags: 14.04, gnome, firefox

I updated Ubuntu 14.04 to the latest stable kernel and I saw that my fonts and themes have become weird.

The font in the files/documents have become much too thin.

[image: Files]

..and my Firefox looks like it has a prehistoric theme..
[image: firefox]

Can someone tell me how to go back to normal?

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

It so happened that somehow Gnome hadn't been installed at all.
So, I went ahead and installed Gnome using

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

And things are back to normal!